# Modifying subplot axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm plotting 2 subplots, and I want each subplot to have different axis scaling.

My current code is:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
axis([0 20 0 1])
plot(t,Ca,'-.',t,Cb,'.',t,Cc);

subplot(2,1,2)
axis([0 5 0 1]);
plot(t2,Ca2,'-.',t2,Cb2,'.',t2,Cc2);
```

But both subplots plot as if no axis was specified.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,Ca,'-.',t,Cb,'.',t,Cc);
axis([0 20 0 1])

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t2,Ca2,'-.',t2,Cb2,'.',t2,Cc2);
axis([0 5 0 1]);
```

plot will refigure the axes, so you have to call axis AFTER the last plot.